# How to remove indicator line of TextField in Androidx Compose Material?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I would like to remove the purple line/indicator (see the following image) of TextField.
Is that possible or should I create my own custom TextField to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to change the color from purple to your desired colour or you completely wants to remove the blinker line and other.

Comment: `TextField` is Compose UI's text-entry composable following Material Design guidelines. `BaseTextField` is the foundation for plain text entry, without the Material Design elements. Long-term, it is unclear how much configuration they will offer that allows `TextField` to deviate from Material Design. Eventually, the community will create more flexible alternatives, for projects that do not want a ~100% Material Design look.

Comment: I would like to completely remove the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You use `TextField` in that you can give the `activeColor` to `Color.Transparent`

Note: `activeColor` is not only for indicator, its for label bottom indicator and cursor

Ex:

```
    var text: String by mutableStateOf("")
    TextField(value = text, onValueChange = {
        text = it
    }, activeColor = Color.Transparent)
```

As per the document, `activeColor` is

> activeColor the color of the label, bottom indicator and the cursor
> when the text field is in focus

If you want to use your own you can try `BaseTextField`

Comment: I tested this solutions but it didnt work in my Compose version

Comment: what is the version you are using?

Comment: I updated to latest version it worked. Not fully because the line is still there when TextField is not selected, but it is acceptable

Comment: @Trinity, For that we should use inactiveColor, but the problem is inactiveColor is color of either the input text or placeholder when the text field is in focus, and the color of the label and bottom indicator when the text field is not in focus so if we give the color as Transparent then the text will not be visible. This is a very early stage, so later they might improve more on this API.

Answer (score 27):

This has been changed in the recent Jetpack Compose UI Beta release **1.0.0-beta01** now you can pass the

**TextFieldDefaults** with desired colors.

```
 colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            backgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
        )
```

example

```
TextField(
        value = searchText,
        onValueChange = { Log.d(HOME_COMPONENT, it) },
        label = { Text(text = "Search") },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        leadingIcon = {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_search),
                contentDescription = "search"
            )
        },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            backgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
        )
    )
```

image:
[image]

or if you want to customize the component according to your UI/UX then use the **BasicTextField**

```
@Composable
fun ToolbarComponent() {
    var searchText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_search),
            contentDescription = "search",
            modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp),
            tint = iconTintColor
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))

        BasicTextField(
            value = searchText,
            onValueChange = { searchText = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp), color = Color.LightGray)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
            decorationBox = {
                Text(text = "Search")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

**Edit: 31 May 2023**

In Latest Stable version 1.4.7 `TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors` is deprecated so now we can change the default colors using `TextFieldDefaults.colors` in TextField.

```
 colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                cursorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
                focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White,
            )
```

Comment: You saved me a trouble thank you!

Comment: One may also want to set `errorIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,`

Answer (score 6):

Starting with `1.2.0-alpha04` you can use the **`TextFieldDecorationBox`** together with `BasicTextField` to build a custom text field based on Material Design text fields.

In your case you can apply the **`indicatorLine`** modifier to define the **`focusedIndicatorLineThickness`** and the **`unfocusedIndicatorLineThickness`** parameters:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val singleLine = true
val enabled = true
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
BasicTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    modifier = Modifier
        .indicatorLine(enabled, false,
            interactionSource,
            TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(),
            focusedIndicatorLineThickness = 0.dp,
            unfocusedIndicatorLineThickness = 0.dp
        )
        .background(
            TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors().backgroundColor(enabled).value,
            TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldShape
        )
        .width(TextFieldDefaults.MinWidth),
    singleLine = singleLine,
    interactionSource = interactionSource
) { innerTextField ->
    TextFieldDecorationBox(
        value = text,
        innerTextField = innerTextField,
        enabled = enabled,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        label = { Text("Label") }
    )
}
```

[image]

Otherwise you can use `TextField` defining these attributes:

- **`focusedIndicatorColor`**
- **`unfocusedIndicatorColor`**
- **`disabledIndicatorColor`**

Something like:

```
    TextField(
        ....
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = .....,
            focusedIndicatorColor =  Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Transparent)
    )
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Similar question: How to remove the underline appearing under the current word, like the one under "indicator" word above? Is it a OS behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Actually (version alpha 7) this is the easiest version I have found to remove Divider.

Set `activeColor` and `inactiveColor` to `Color.Transparent` in order to hide the indicator line under the TextField, whatever his state.

If you add only `inactiveColor` to `Color.Transparent`, the line will be invisible only when TextField is not focused

Add `textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White)` in order to display the color, whenever if the TextField is focused or not.

This solution will remove the line, but also the cursor indicator. It's not the best for the moment but it's also the alpha actually on Compose.

```
TextField(
    value = MyValue,
    onValueChange = { },
    textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White),
    activeColor = Color.Transparent,
    inactiveColor = Color.Transparent,
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(20)
)
```

[image]